# Two http calls in node.js

Tags: node.js

so my problem is this. I have two https requests. The first request gets accesss token and passes it to the second request which is getting orders info from the server. If these two requests are in separate files it works but I have to copy the access token manually, post it to the second file and then run the node file. I want all this to happens in one file. First parts work ok, I'm able to get the access token but then I get an error. "fault":{"type":"InvalidAuthorizationHeaderException","message":"The request is unauthorized. In the 'Authorization' header, the 'Bearer ' is expected."  Thank you in advance

```
const https = require('https');

var Base64 = { _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=", encode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n, r, i, s, o, u, a; var f = 0; e = Base64._utf8_encode(e); while (f < e.length) { n = e.charCodeAt(f++); r = e.charCodeAt(f++); i = e.charCodeAt(f++); s = n >> 2; o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4; u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6; a = i & 63; if (isNaN(r)) { u = a = 64 } else if (isNaN(i)) { a = 64 } t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a) } return t }, decode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n, r, i; var s, o, u, a; var f = 0; e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g, ""); while (f < e.length) { s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); n = s << 2 | o >> 4; r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2; i = (u & 3) << 6 | a; t = t + String.fromCharCode(n); if (u != 64) { t = t + String.fromCharCode(r) } if (a != 64) { t = t + String.fromCharCode(i) } } t = Base64._utf8_decode(t); return t }, _utf8_encode: function (e) { e = e.replace(/rn/g, "n"); var t = ""; for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) { var r = e.charCodeAt(n); if (r < 128) { t += String.fromCharCode(r) } else if (r > 127 && r < 2048) { t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 | 192); t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128) } else { t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 12 | 224); t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 & 63 | 128); t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128) } } return t }, _utf8_decode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n = 0; var r = c1 = c2 = 0; while (n < e.length) { r = e.charCodeAt(n); if (r < 128) { t += String.fromCharCode(r); n++ } else if (r > 191 && r < 224) { c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1); t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63); n += 2 } else { c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1); c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2); t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63); n += 3 } } return t } };
var encoded = Base64.encode("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" + ":" + "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
var basic_auth = "Basic " + encoded;

var text = "";

const options = {
    hostname: 'hidden for security reasons',
    port: 443,
    path: 'hidden for security reasons',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': basic_auth
    }

};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log("Infomation from the Auth Secure Client API CALL");
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);
    console.log("THE CALL ENDS HERE");

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        //process.stdout.write(d);// here I was testing that I get body from the server
        text = JSON.parse(d);
        text = text.access_token;
        //process.stdout.write(text); // printing the access_token making sure that I get it
    })
});

req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error)
});

req.end();

const data = JSON.stringify({
    "query":
    {
        "text_query": { "fields": ["customer_email"], "search_phrase": "martin@test.com" }
    },
    "select": "(**)",
    "sorts": [{ "field": "customer_name", "sort_order": "asc" }]
});

var auth = 'Bearer ' + text;

const options2 = {
    hostname: 'hidden for security reasons',
    port: 443,
    path: 'hidden for security reasons',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'x-dw-client-id': 'hidden for security reasons',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + text
    }
};


const req2 = https.request(options2, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d)
    })
});

req2.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error)
});

req2.write(data);
req2.end();
```

Comment: Hey ! Looks like a classic asynchronous problem. Your 2nd request is sent before the 1st request finished. You have to wait until the 1st request ist finished, then sent the 2nd request.

Comment: You may wish to use a higher-level, promise-supporting HTTP(S) library such as node-fetch to make this easier for you.

Comment: I was assuming this but wasn't sure. I'm new to this environment, so I decide to ask first before diving in asynchronous documentation. Thank you brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good that you are using native module for making network calls. HTTPS is event based having mainly 'data', 'error', 'end' events. After executing the https call we get data in chunks. When the 'end' event is triggered that means the https call is complete and we have received all the chunks of the data.

As Node.js is asynchronous all the I/O calls are handled by the worker threads and the main thread keeps on executing the code. As here you have dependency on the first http call, so you will have wait for it to finish.

You can use other modules which makes life easier but native modules are good in early stage of your learning and understanding its working.

```js
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log("Infomation from the Auth Secure Client API CALL");
        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('headers:', res.headers);
        console.log("THE CALL ENDS HERE");

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            //process.stdout.write(d);// here I was testing that I get body from the server
            text += chunk;
            text = text.access_token;
            //process.stdout.write(text); // printing the access_token making sure that I get it
        });
        
        res.on('end', () => {
            text = JSON.parse(text);
            access_token = text.access_token;
            // after the first https request is complete, we will call the second https request
            secondCall(access_token);
        });
        
    });

    //Making second https call
    const secondCall = (access_token) => {
        const options2 = {
          hostname: 'hidden for security reasons',
          port: 443,
          path: 'hidden for security reasons',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'x-dw-client-id': 'hidden for security reasons',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Content-Length': data.length,
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token 
          }
      };
      
      //Now here you can call the second request 
      
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and explain it really helps alot when you learning!  It works.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you're not waiting for one query to finish before making the other.

Here's a quick reformulation with

- a promise-based wrapper (which may well be buggy, ahem) for making requests
- an async function that chains the two calls
- an example of how to call the promise-returning async function from a non-async context.

Hope this helps.

```
const https = require("https");

function requestP(options, data = null) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(options, res => {
      let data = "";
      res.on("data", d => (data += d));
      res.on("end", () => {
        resolve({ res, data });
      });
    });
    req.on("error", reject);
    if (data) req.write(data);
    req.end();
  });
}

async function doThings() {
  const r1 = await requestP({
    hostname: "hidden for security reasons",
    port: 443,
    path: "hidden for security reasons",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: "Basic ...",
    },
  });
  const accessToken = JSON.parse(r1.data).access_token;
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    query: {
      text_query: {
        fields: ["customer_email"],
        search_phrase: "martin@test.com",
      },
    },
    select: "(**)",
    sorts: [{ field: "customer_name", sort_order: "asc" }],
  });
  const r2 = await requestP({
    hostname: "hidden for security reasons",
    port: 443,
    path: "hidden for security reasons",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "x-dw-client-id": "hidden for security reasons",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Content-Length": data.length,
      Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
    },
  }, data);
  return r2;
}

doThings().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sending http request is an asynchronous task. So it may take various times. In this case, your second request fulfilled before the first one. Use a module like `axios` for handling requests.

```
const axios = require('axios');

var Base64 = { _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=", encode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n, r, i, s, o, u, a; var f = 0; e = Base64._utf8_encode(e); while (f < e.length) { n = e.charCodeAt(f++); r = e.charCodeAt(f++); i = e.charCodeAt(f++); s = n >> 2; o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4; u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6; a = i & 63; if (isNaN(r)) { u = a = 64 } else if (isNaN(i)) { a = 64 } t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a) } return t }, decode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n, r, i; var s, o, u, a; var f = 0; e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g, ""); while (f < e.length) { s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); n = s << 2 | o >> 4; r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2; i = (u & 3) << 6 | a; t = t + String.fromCharCode(n); if (u != 64) { t = t + String.fromCharCode(r) } if (a != 64) { t = t + String.fromCharCode(i) } } t = Base64._utf8_decode(t); return t }, _utf8_encode: function (e) { e = e.replace(/rn/g, "n"); var t = ""; for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) { var r = e.charCodeAt(n); if (r < 128) { t += String.fromCharCode(r) } else if (r > 127 && r < 2048) { t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 | 192); t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128) } else { t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 12 | 224); t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 & 63 | 128); t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128) } } return t }, _utf8_decode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n = 0; var r = c1 = c2 = 0; while (n < e.length) { r = e.charCodeAt(n); if (r < 128) { t += String.fromCharCode(r); n++ } else if (r > 191 && r < 224) { c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1); t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63); n += 2 } else { c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1); c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2); t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63); n += 3 } } return t } };
var encoded = Base64.encode("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" + ":" + "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
var basic_auth = "Basic " + encoded;

var text = "";

const options = {
  hostname: 'hidden for security reasons',
  port: 443,
  path: 'hidden for security reasons',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': basic_auth
  }

};

axios(options)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    const options2 = {
      hostname: 'hidden for security reasons',
      port: 443,
      path: 'hidden for security reasons',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'x-dw-client-id': 'hidden for security reasons',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + text
      }
    };
    return axios(options2);
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!